# How to add scroll view on uiimage in uialertview in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimage

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem to add UIscrollview on UIImage in UIAlertView.
My code is Like this

In ViewDidLoad

```
newsimage.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressgestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [longpressgestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(imgLongPressed:)];
    longpressgestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [newsimage addGestureRecognizer: longpressgestureRecognizer];

- (void) imgLongPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(200, 200); // set the width and height
    UIImage *resizedImage = [self resizeImage:newsimage.image imageSize:size];
    UIImage *wonImage = resizedImage;
    imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [imageView setImage:wonImage];
    alertViewpress = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                message:@""
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    //check if os version is 7 or above
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        [alertViewpress setValue:imageView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    }else{
        [alertViewpress addSubview:imageView];
    }
    [alertViewpress show];
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismiss:) withObject:alertViewpress afterDelay:1.0];
}
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    [alertView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
}
-(void)dismiss:(UIAlertView*)alert
{
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}

-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image imageSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    // here is the scaled image which has been changed to the size specified
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

How can I add Scroll view so that I can scroll image or How can I change size of UIAlertView or is it is possible to change the size of UIAlertView.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You can't change the alert view or change the size of alert view.You can try with custom view.

Comment: @user3182143 Can I add Scrollview in this code?

Comment: Add the images in scroll view.Don't set the images in alert view.

Comment: @user3182143 That the problem I am facing.

Comment: @user3182143 How can I add Custom view in Long press gesture method and also add this code. Please share any example or code.

Comment: If you have not got the solution please tell me I will help you.

Comment: @user3182143 No not get  the solution

Comment: Is it Ok for you if i give you button back ground images coding in scroll view?

Answer (score 0):

I give you what you ask.Your view name is customView and you set frame for that.Now the code looks like below.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressOnCustomView = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressOnCustomView:)];
longPressOnCustomView.delegate = self;
customView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[customView addGestureRecognizer:longPressOnCustomView];

#pragma mark Long Press Gesture Recognizer
- (void)longPressOnCustomView:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
       //Code for scrolling the image
    }
}
```

Comment: I need code to scroll in UIAlertview or CustomView. I have already added code for gesture.

Comment: How do you need images in scroll view?